# Regex to match arbitrary number of tokens in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of lines of speaker information in the following format (Note: the list is from the [LibriSpeech](http://openslr.org/12/) corpus):

`58   | M | train-other-500  | 30.06 | George Coutts`

The `|` (pipe) divide the line into:

- speaker id
- sex
- subset of the corpus
- minutes of recorded audio
- speaker name

I want to use a regex to extract this information in Python. I have used the following regex so far:

`(?P<speaker_id>.*)\|(?P<sex>.*)\|(?P<subset>.*)\|(?P<minutes>.*)\|(?P<speaker_name>.*)(?=.*)`

This works for almost all cases except if the speaker name contains pipe characters itself (which is the case for at least one speaker). Then the regex splits up the different groups in a wrong way by greedily matching the first group (which then also contains the sex and the subset information).

See https://regex101.com/r/GQzWOg/2 for a demo.

How can I make the regex match everything after the last pipe as the `speaker_name` group?

I have already tried experimenting with [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but I really can't get my head around this...

Comment: `speaker_id, sex, subset, minutes, speaker_name = line.split(' | ', 4)`

Comment: Additionally you should be sanitizing your data.  Your delimiters should be escaped so they are not seen as delimiters when they are added to your data (i.e. wrap strings with quotes or replace the characters with something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make your regex a bit more specific:

```
^(?P<speaker_id>\d+)\s*\|\s*(?P<sex>[MF])\s*\|\s*(?P<subset>.*?)\s*\|\s*(?P<minutes>\d[\d.]*)\s*\|\s*(?P<speaker_name>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQzWOg/3)

Breaking it down:

- `^` - start of string (or line if you use `re.M` flag)
- `(?P<speaker_id>\d+)` - 1+ digits
- `\s*\|\s*` - `|` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?P<sex>[MF])` - `M` or `F` (for gender)
- `\s*\|\s*`  - `|` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?P<subset>.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible
- `\s*\|\s*` - `|` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?P<minutes>\d[\d.]*)` - a digit and then 0+ digits or `.`
- `\s*\|\s*` - `|` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?P<speaker_name>.*)` - any 0+ chars other than a newline up to the end of the string / line.

Comment: That did the trick! Additionally, your explanations helped me parsing similar other lines better. Thanks Wiktor!